# No errors present => ReactDOM.render() method nowhere to be found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to learn more about React.js from the ground up.

While reading the documentation I found that using `ReactDOM.render(element, Document.getElementById("root"))` would pass the JSX referenced by the word element to the element with `id="root"` in an HTML file. [This](https://reactjs.org/redirect-to-codepen/components-and-props/rendering-a-component) shows what I mean.

When I looked through [my repo](https://github.com/holdermatthew5/cookie_stand_admin.git) created with the command `npx create-next-app --example with-tailwindcss <app-name>` I noticed that not only is there no `ReactDOM.render()` method being used anywhere in the file structure, but there is also no HTML file anywhere in the repo and all of the data seems to flow into `index.js` which returns the final JSX elements, but I can't find where that Home function is called as `<Home />` anywhere.

Is there an HTML file hidden somewhere that I'm missing or is there some sort of more advanced level coding at play here that picks up the return from the Home function and does the `ReactDom.render()` functionality some other way? Maybe like in binary or with transpiling or something? I'd really appreciate some documentation that explains this in detail with examples.

Comment: Keep in mind that Next.js is a framework that builds a layer of abstraction on top of React itself. Some of the things React exposes are hidden away in Next.js. For a better understanding of Next.js I'd recommend going through their [official tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app).

Answer (score 0):

This repo is powered by [NextJs](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started), so yes - there is an extra level on top of React, looking for any React component in `pages/index.js` to render the root, by naming conventions of framework, there are few places mentioning this in [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs)